# C++ embedding Python

Tags: python, c++, include, embed

i wanted to run Python-Scripts with C++.

At my book, there is following:

```
#include <Python.h>
... at main function some calls
```

But at compiling the Compiler can't find the Python header file.

How can i fix this?

Comment: depends on the platform you are using. On linux, you'll need to install the `python-devel` package (how you do that also depends on the specific distro).

Comment: On a Debian-based distribution, the package would actually be called `python-dev`.

Comment: i have linux mint, how should it called there?

Comment: Don't work yet, can't find the header...I donwloaded the python-dev..but can't find header-file...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Linux Mint `sudo apt-get install python-dev` should do the job.  This will get and install the python development files.

This should put the include files at `/usr/include/python2.7/` so you need to add `-l /usr/include/python2.7/` to your compiler flags.

`

Comment: I installed this, but at compiling:
martin@ThinkPad ~/Schreibtisch $ g++ pytest.cpp -o pytest
pytest.cpp:1:20: fatal error: Python.h: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
 #include <Python.h>
                    ^
compilation terminated.

Comment: Don't work yet, can't find the header...I donwloaded the python-dev..but can't find header-file...

Comment: See above about the path.

Comment: Don't work...I add the Path-Linker, but still same error, but at this folder the Python.h file is in...